# Access on Record Type

Tags: profile, record-type, user, record-access-level

I am currently not getting access to a particular Record Type ID though I have logged in from an User with System Administrator Profile.

Can someone explain what to do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Did you check the system admin profile has access to the record type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to System Admin Profile & check the Object Settings. Select the Object.
Make sure that the checkbox against Assigned Record Types is checked for the required Record Type.